# Powershell function to invoke a set of commands from different directories and save their output to a file

Tags: powershell

I have the following directory structure:

C:\UserX\A\Bat
C:\UserX\B\Bat
C:\UserX\C\Bat

and in each Bat directory there are 2 batch files StartClient.bat and StartServer.Bat

I would like a powershell function that I could pass an array of strings that contains the directory names [A,B] and then in each directory Invoke the server batch file followed by the client batch file and save any output from the server batch file to server.log and from the client to client.log.

I am fairly new to powershell and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
"A", "B" | %{
    & "C:\UserX\$_\StartServer.bat" >> server.log
    & "C:\UserX\$_\StartClient.bat" >> client.log }
```

**Explanation:**

Pipe your list of names to the `foreach` command (alias %). For each item in the list, execute each bat script. The `$_` will be replaced with the current iterator argument in the pipeline (i.e. "A", then "B"). The redirection operator (`>>`) then appends the output to the log file.

To turn this into a function, just create a function that takes the list as an argument:

```
function Start-ClientAndServer($items)
{

    $items | %{
        & "C:\UserX\$_\StartServer.bat" >> server.log
        & "C:\UserX\$_\StartClient.bat" >> client.log 
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem there is that it will dump server and client logs in the current directory and overwrite them for each item in $items.

Comment: @x0n: No, the ">>" will append the contents to any existing log. I guess it's not clear whether the OP wants them all appended like that or if he wants individual log files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That has solved the problem. The ForEach command and the $_ did the job.

Comment: when I commented first, it wasn't ">>" it was ">" - the answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for '>command< | out-file -append'